# Как клонировать нужную ветку?

Tags: git, git-clone

Как клонировать удаленный репозиторий и получить иную ветку, чем `master` (т.е. по умолчанию)?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`git clone http://whatever.git -b branch-name`

Answer (score 17):

Этот вариант склонирует ПОЛНОСТЬЮ весь репозиторий и просто переключится на ветку branch-name:

```
git clone http://whatever.git -b branch-name
```

Иногда нужно склонировать ТОЛЬКО конкретную ветку, тогда:

```
git clone --branch=branch-name http://whatever.git
```

Еще иногда может потребоваться склонировать репозиторий без многолетней истории его коммитов, тогда нужно использовать параметр --depth=5, где 5 - количество коммитов от последнего:

```
git clone --depth=1 --branch=branch-name http://whatever.git
```

Answer (score 12):

git clone создает копию удаленного (в общем случае) репозитория. Чтобы получить бранч из удаленного репозитория нужно после git clone выполнить:

```
git checkout -b [branch] [remotename]/[branch]
```

или

```
git checkout --track [remotename]/[branch]
```

Answer (score 1):

В ответах выше клонируется весь репозиторий, что легко проверить командой "git branch -a".
Может понадобиться клонировать только определённую ветку:

```
git clone --single-branch -b [branchname] [repository]
```

Чтобы клонировать только последнюю версию (без истории):

```
git clone --depth=1 --single-branch -b [branchname] [repository]
```